# How do you delete an asset from CloudKit in Swift?

Tags: swift, cloudkit

I've been scouring the internet and have not been able to find anything regarding how to delete an Asset (such as an image) in CloudKit using Swift? In the CloudKit dashboard, you can click the red X under the Asset field to delete it; I just need to know how to do this in Swift. The only search results that come up when I try to research this involves deleting a Record.

Comment: I tried record.setObject(nil, forKey: "image"), however this does not seem to work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from the CKAsset documentation:

> You cannot delete asset data directly from the server. When you no longer want the data associated with an asset, remove all asset objects that point to that data from your records. For example, for a record that contains an asset as a field, set the value of the field to nil. When no asset objects refer to the data, the server lazily deletes the asset data at some point in the future. (Exactly when is not specified, but assume at least several days.)

Comment: Interesting.. ok, well I did try setting the object to "nil" for the "image" key; I'll keep checking in a few days to see if the image eventually gets deleted from the container in CloudKit. Thanks for the response!

Comment: UPDATE: It seems to be working now! I had to rerun the query and the image assets got deleted right away. Thanks Manuel for that very helpful piece of info!